# Get http status code after redirect in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response.redirect

When we redirect to another page (for example to a page in other website), server response with http status code. if everythings is OK, return 200.
When i call `Response.Redirect` how can i detect the http status code that return from remote server?
I want log in database redirect was performed correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You redirect the visitor's browser to a different URL. If that URL does not point to a server you control, you cannot see how that request went.

Comment: But i have seen in some website, that log 200 OK or another code after redirect

Answer (score 0):

When you write `Response.Redirect(...)` this causes your site to send an HTTP 302 (Moved) back to the client browser...and that is the end of the story as far as your server is concerned - the connection to the client is closed and you have no more interaction with them.

You simply cannot detect that the *client browser* then loaded up the resource indicated by your 302, unless that resource happens to be on your own server -- which in your case, it isn't.

The only way I can see for you to check this in any semi-meanginful way is if you do a check on behalf of the client first *in your own code behind* by issuing your own HTTP GET for the redirect location...but that still only tells you that the remote resource was available *to you* at the time you checked.

But it's still impossible for you to say that based on you getting HTTP 200 that the client will also be able to access it (firewall, poor connection, black listed, leaving aside the issue that now you are putting double the request load on that remote resource..) and to be honest I wouldn't recommend even bothering to do this because it's not a 100% reliable method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this may not be the perfect solution but it is certainly an acceptable work around in my book. The idea here is that you can determine what the expected HttpStatusCode should be for a given URL.

```
public HttpStatusCode GetRedirectStatusCode(string destinationUrl)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    request.Timeout = 180000;

    using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        return response.StatusCode;
    }
}
```